# How can I use the correct routing to display an HTML page with Flask?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am lost with python and flask as I do not understand how the routing structure works to navigate between HTML pages.

Deployed to heroku my structure is:

```
/my_app_name/
app.py
config.py
drivers.html
Procfile  
requirements.txt
```

the app.py file is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World from Python!'

@app.route('/')
def drivers():
    drivers = db.drivers.select()
    return render_template('drivers.html')
    #return HttpResponse('/drivers.html', json.dumps(result), content_type='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

config.py is:

```
 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'heroku_database_uri_string) #connection is OK, no problem here
```

drivers.html is:

```
{% block body %}
  <ul>
  {% for driver in drivers %}
    <li><h2>{{ driver.driver_name }}</h2>
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

When I navigate to myapp.heroku.com/ I get the "hello world from pyhton" fine but when I navigate to myapp.heroku.com/drivers.html

I get a '404' error.

So, 2 questions:

1) Why 404? What is wrong?

2) I assume it is, but is the entire structure flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely must have noticed these lines:

```
@app.route(...)
```

in your code. They define the routes. You have two handlers pointing at "/", whereas presumably you want the drivers handler pointing at "/drivers": so change the argument you're passing to `route`.

Also, you shouldn't be thinking in terms of HTML pages, and you shouldn't be trying to give your routes ".html" suffixes. Just use "drivers", and navigate to myapp.heroku.com/drivers.

Finally, there's no need to upload to Heroku to test this: just run the local development server. Please note that all this is well described in the Flask docs; you should read them.

Comment: thanks that partly helps me. I have read the flask docs but have not fully understood them. I will, without doubt, be back for more help!